# SLF4J-Logback : Multiple Pattern based on Log Level

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

Logback is used because we need some Appenders which are not provided by log4j .

**Requirement:** For Log level Error we want to use custom pattern which will add information based on stack trace.

For all other log level it should use simple pattern.

All the log output should go in same file.

**Below things are tried :** Created two Appenders, one for error log level and other for other log level.
When same destination file is used for both Appenders then error log are not getting written to file.
When diffrent destination file is used for both appenders then two files are getting created one with error log level and other with all other log level

With log4j2 found some pointers but with logback unable to find solution so far.

Can someone please suggest some approach

Comment: any idea how this can be fixed, the proposed solution "prudent" is not working ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the appender config, set prudent to true. This will allow multiple appenders to write to the same file.

Comment: This will solve my problem but still I don't want to use this solution because it has performance overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Exploding the answer from Prasanth Nair. In the manual of logback https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html you can find

> In `prudent` mode, FileAppender will safely write to the specified file,
>   even in the presence of other FileAppender instances running in
>   different JVMs, potentially running on different hosts. The default
>   value for prudent mode is false.

Here is an example config:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!-- Support multiple-JVM writing to the same log file -->
    <prudent>true</prudent>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory> 
      <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```